# Is it possible to perform a single transaction across multiple fargate instances using documentDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, transactions, aws-documentdb

I have a use-case where i need to perform documentDB write operations on three different collections using AWS Batch with fargate instances in Java. I would receive S3 files which contain data to write in to documentDB and each fargate instance receives a file and performs write operation on a specific collection based on the file metadata.

Usually when i need to perform a transaction inside a single fargate, it is straight forward. But i want to know if its possible to perform a transaction across multiple fargate instances running in parallel to write data across multiple collections with documentDB?